# Insert into.....values((select statement), value1, value2, value3) Select statement returns Multiple colums

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here's what I am trying to do..

```
INSERT IGNORE into table1(`name`,`phone`,`address`,`province`,`col1`, `col2`) 
VALUES ((SELECT `name`,`phone`,`address`,`province` FROM table2 
         WHERE `country`= 'Canada'),'val1', 'val2');
```

Select statement basically returns multiple queries. How to handle scenario using a combo of values and select statement returning, multiple queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE into table1(`name`,`phone`,`address`,`province`,`col1`, `col2`) 
Select `name`,`phone`,`address`,`province`,'val1','val2'
from table2 
where `country`= 'Canada'
```

Comment: Working Thank you !!